# Mouseover span popup box with descripsion from data atribute

Tags: javascript, popup, dataset, dom-events

How looks logos.

[image: how looks logos]

I have span with some logo and I have in that span `data-description="some text"`. When I mouse over that logo I want popup one little box with text in "Some text". I hope you understand me. Please only JavaScript.

```
 <div class="">
                  <a href="#"><span><img src="images/weekend.png" class="pic-width border-radius" data-description="This is good if you travel alone"></span></a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to apply any CSS to it, then you can just use the `title` attribute; ever since HTML5 it works with any element:

```
<span title="This is good if you travel alone">
    <img src="images/weekend.png" class="pic-width border-radius" />
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not what i need..I need some BOX on TOP of logo with that text.